# Where can I find the "Enter" function that is called in this code?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and am confused by the following [code](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.cpp). The comments indicate what I think each line does.

```
void State::Manager::Run(State& entranceState) {  //pass a variable of type State by reference
    current = &entranceState;  //get the address of entrance state and store it in current
    current->Enter();   //call the enter method of the object that current points to
```

Based on the above I would think that State has a method called "Enter" (because the last of the three lines calls a method of type Enter() on an object of type State. But if I search the file for State (the link is above) for the Enter method, I don't see this method. What am I missing? Where can I find the Enter function?

Comment: Check states.h for Enter.  Check all the files.

Comment: How is `current` declared? `State * current`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in [states.h](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.h) as

```
virtual void Enter() {}
```

In other words, it is virtual method, and normally does nothing unless redefined by some class derived from `State`.

Comment: It's virtual, but it's not pure virtual. It does not have to be defined anywhere - it's defined right in `State` (with an empty body).

Comment: A quick `grep -r '::Enter '` will show the other definitions.

Comment: That is exactly what I said - it does nothing by default, but can be redefined by derived class

Comment: @abe3: this makes it possible to create extensible interfaces. Essentially this is a hook. By default nothing happens, but if you want to provide some custom behavior in some derived class, simply define another `Enter()` method - that's all it takes.